Family living at an underground shelter goes out
I remember the plot of a film that I watched a long time ago, I want to know the name, if someone can help me:
During the cold war, a family of one boy and a couple stocked resources enough to live several years at an underground shelter, they thought the surface was bombarded by the war.
The parents taught the boy as particular teachers, with books and stuff they had. Energy was generated by a spinning bike. The time passed, the boy grew up.
They decided the son, now an adult, should go to the surface in quest of refill the  resources that was running out, the father gave some papers he believe could worth some penny, indeed it was IBM scrip that now worth a fortune.
After some while the guy returned in order to report to his father what he had seen, he said there are mutants at the surface, because he met a transvestite.

The movie is "Blast from the Past" from 1999.

In 1962 an eccentric scientist who, like so many people at the same, thought that a nuclear war between the U.S. and the Soviet Union was possible, built a bomb shelter in his basement. During the Cuban missile crisis, when he thought things were going escalate took his pregnant wife into the bomb shelter. When a plane flying over lost control, the pilot bailed out and the plane crashed into their house which activated the shelter's locks (designed not to open for 35 years). She gives birth to a boy whom they name Adam. So Adam grows up being taught and exposed to all culture up to 1962. When the locks open, they're shocked to see how the world has changed they decide to stay inside. However their supplies have run out, so Adam goes out to get some more but gets lost and is helped by a girl called Eve.




